# Make Menu have a slideToggle Effect and push below elements down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a nice Mega Menu from **[CODROPS](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/05/horizontal-drop-down-menu/)** and I'm trying to customize it to have:

1) a slideToggle effect

2) When the menu is opened to push the below div element down (IE: not overlapping the below elements)

[Here is my JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3vn6c/)

This is what I've done so far:

1) I know **very basic** jquery and usually I know how to apply a **slideToggle** effect but I can't seem to get it right with their javascript code, so I'm left guessing where to place it but having no success. I've tried researching online but can't find a solution.

2) To make the element below the menu get pushed down, I know to make the **position relative** in the css below but that just breaks the menus float when it's activated.

```
/* sub-menu */
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #47a3da;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

It would be nice to have the elements below pushed down but the slideToggle effect is a bit more important to me...

Comment: "I know to make the position relative in the css below but that just breaks the menus float when it's activated." **Then I would re-do the CSS accordingly.** It seems you know how to fix the basic problem, after that it's just a matter of styling.

Comment: Yes true, I think to sort that issue out would be to separate the list items from the drop down content as athms suggests ... but would anyone know how to incorporate the slideToggle?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to refactor this a bit to get it to work the way you want it to.

The .cbp-hrsub element containing the sub text is positioned absolutely, overlaying any text below. You would need to remove `position:absolute` to revert to the browser default `position:static`.

However, as the .cbp-hrsub element is part of each menu `<li>`, this pushes the other `<li>` elements down.

I'd suggest splitting the HTML out so that your menu `<li>` elements are separate to your sub text elements. Contain the subtext elements in a new `<ul>` and get these to slide down on click of the associated menu item link.

Comment: I see what you're saying ... I need to put the List items separate to the drop down content though I'm thinking this won't work because of the way the javascript functions?

Comment: Yes, you might struggle to get this to work with the existing JavaScript from CODROPS. I'm not familar with the CODROPS script itself but you may find it easier to build your own Mega Menu from scratch to get this working the way you want it to.

Comment: Well with my javascript knowledge at the moment it'll be impossible for me to write it myself unfortunately. There is this script that structured like the way we want it: http://www.impressivewebs.com/mega-menus-ajax-jquery/ ... but I've given up with trying to make that drop down menu to NOT load up external pages (I don't understand why upload content from external pages as it's non SEO friendly!). So in a way it's basically what I want but another issue is that I can't make it responsive because of the height issue involved (otherwise the animations are fickle) - FRUSTRATING!!!

Comment: Otherwise with regards to the slideToggle would you know where to apply this in the javascript? I was pretty confident I'd know how to but I'm obviously missing something

Comment: You could add slideDown() and slideUp() function calls into the existing open() and close() functions already present in the JSFiddle you provided. To do this you would need to target the correct subtext list item using something like `$('ul.subText li:eq(' + index + ')').slideDown();`